# Unnecessary action pane items in my MMC snap-in

Tags: mmc

I am developing a MMC 3.0 snap-in. I have custom actions to be displayed in the right had side MMC action pane, which I have done using

ParentFormView.SelectionData.ActionsPaneItems.Add(CustomAction)

Things are working fine so far.

My problem is - Windows by default also paints actions such as 'View', 'New window from here', 'Help' etc in the action pane when my snap-in loads. How do I programatically disable these default actions?

Answer (score 0):

Those are "default" actions, and Microsoft has not released any documentation on how to do that.